# Mapping Exception in Symfony / Doctrine: The target-entity App\DocumentBundle\File cannot be found in 'App\DocumentBundle\Entity\Document#file'

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to upgrade an application running on Symfony 3.4 to version 4.4. I already did multiple changes and adaptions according to the official documentation for upgrading Symfony. Neverthelesse, I'm stuck now with the following error that comes up when I try to run a command in the terminal or access the application via browser.

**Mapping Exception**

```
Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException:
The target-entity App\DocumentBundle\File cannot be found in 'App\DocumentBundle\Entity\Document#file'.

  at /srv/http/sp7/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php:772
  at Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException::invalidTargetEntityClass('App\\DocumentBundle\\File', 'App\\DocumentBundle\\Entity\\Document', 'file')
     (/srv/http/sp7/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php:1032)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo->validateAssociations()
     (/srv/http/sp7/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:266)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->validateRuntimeMetadata(object(ClassMetadata), object(ClassMetadata))
     (/srv/http/sp7/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:245)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata(object(ClassMetadata), object(ClassMetadata), false, array())
     (/srv/http/sp7/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:306)
  at Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('App\\DocumentBundle\\Entity\\Document')
     (/srv/http/sp7/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:78)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('App\\DocumentBundle\\Entity\\Document')
     (/srv/http/sp7/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:185)
  at Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('App\\DocumentBundle\\Entity\\Document')
     (/srv/http/sp7/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:91)
  at Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata()
     (/srv/http/sp7/vendor/mgilet/notification-bundle/NotifiableDiscovery.php:76)
  at Mgilet\NotificationBundle\NotifiableDiscovery->discoverNotifiables()
     (/srv/http/sp7/vendor/mgilet/notification-bundle/NotifiableDiscovery.php:40)
  at Mgilet\NotificationBundle\NotifiableDiscovery->__construct(object(EntityManager), object(CachedReader))
     (/srv/http/sp7/var/cache/dev/ContainerSAZB8iG/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:6135)
  at ContainerSAZB8iG\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer->getMgilet_NotificationService()
     (/srv/http/sp7/var/cache/dev/ContainerSAZB8iG/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:7481)
  at ContainerSAZB8iG\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer->getTwigService()
     (/srv/http/sp7/var/cache/dev/ContainerSAZB8iG/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:13406)
  at ContainerSAZB8iG\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer->getSensioFrameworkExtra_View_ListenerService()
     (/srv/http/sp7/var/cache/dev/ContainerSAZB8iG/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:4501)
  at ContainerSAZB8iG\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer->ContainerSAZB8iG\{closure}()
     (/srv/http/sp7/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:301)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher::Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\{closure}(object(ControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(EventDispatcher))
     (/srv/http/sp7/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:264)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(Closure), object(Closure), object(Closure), object(Closure), object(Closure), object(Closure)), 'kernel.controller', object(ControllerEvent))
     (/srv/http/sp7/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:239)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->callListeners(array(object(Closure), object(Closure), object(Closure), object(Closure), object(Closure), object(Closure)), 'kernel.controller', object(ControllerEvent))
     (/srv/http/sp7/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:73)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch(object(ControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller')
     (/srv/http/sp7/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:134)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (/srv/http/sp7/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:68)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (/srv/http/sp7/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:201)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (/srv/http/sp7/public/index.php:25)
```

The code itself should store a document and offer the possibility to attach files to the documents. Therefore, I used the Vich/Uploader-Bundle and I suspect that the error somehow is linked to Vich.

Document.php

```
<?php

namespace App\DocumentBundle\Entity;

use App\Entity\FileAwareEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use App\UserBundle\Entity\User as User;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;


/**
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Table(name="document_document", options={"engine"="InnoDB"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\DocumentBundle\Entity\DocumentRepository")
 */
class Document extends FileAwareEntity {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


     /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Groups({"elastica"})
     */
    private $name;


     /**
     *
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"elastica"})
     */
    private $description;


    /**
    *
    * @var string
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
    * @Groups({"elastica"})
    */
   private $headline;


    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\DocumentBundle\Entity\DocumentType")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type", referencedColumnName="id")
    * @ORM\OrderBy({"translationKey" = "ASC"})
    * @var \App\DocumentBundle\Entity\DocumentType
    * @Groups({"elastica"})
    **/
    private $type;

     /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"elastica"})
     */
    private $vkaNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $linkedDocument;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $linkedDocumentExpires;


    /**
     * @var boolean
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"elastica"})
     */
    private $active;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
      */
    private $status_stealth;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $locked;


    /**
     * $var DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"elastica"})
     */
    private $created;

     //     * @Groups({"elastica"})
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="documentsCreated")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="createdBy", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var \App\UserBundle\Entity\User

     **/
    private $createdBy;

    /**
     * $var DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Expression(
     *     "false == this.getStealthException()",
     *     message="The effective date must be in the future!")
     * @Groups({"elastica"})
     */
    private $effective;

    /**
     * $var DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Expression(
     *     "this.getEffective() < this.getExpires()",
     *     message="The expiration date can't be before the effective date")
     */
    private $expires;

    /**
     * $var DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $modified;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="modifiedBy", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var \App\UserBundle\Entity\User
     **/
    private $modifiedBy;

    //     * @Groups({"elastica"})
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Agency", inversedBy="documentagency", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="document_document_agency",
     *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="document_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="iata8", referencedColumnName="iata8")})
     * @var \App\Entity\Agency

     **/
    private $agency;

    /**
     * $var boolean
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $signature;

    /**
     * $var boolean
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $signed;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="documentSigned")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="signedBy", referencedColumnName="id")
    * @var \App\UserBundle\Entity\User
    **/
    private $signedBy;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\DocumentBundle\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="document",cascade={"remove"})
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     **/
    protected $comment;

    //     * @Groups({"elastica"})
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Market", inversedBy="document", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="document_document_market",
     *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="document_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="market_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     * @Assert\Count(
     *      min = "0"
     * )

     **/
    private $market;

    //     * @Groups({"elastica"})
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Airline", inversedBy="document", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="document_document_airline",
     *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="document_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="airline_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     * @Assert\Count(
     *      min = "0"
     * )
     * @var \App\Entity\Airline

     **/
    private $airline;

    //     * @Groups({"elastica"})
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", inversedBy="document", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="document_document_product",
     *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="document_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     * @Assert\Count(
     *      min = "0"
     * )
     * @var \App\Entity\Product

     **/
    private $product;

    //     * @Groups({"elastica"})
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\ReferentialBundle\Entity\Channel1", inversedBy="document", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="document_document_channel",
     *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="document_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="channel_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     * @Assert\Count(
     *      min = "0"
     * )
     * @var \App\ReferentialBundle\Entity\Channel1

     **/

    private $channel;
    /**
     * $var boolean
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $internalCom;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\DocumentBundle\File", mappedBy="entity", cascade={"persist", "merge", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @Assert\Valid()
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     **/
    protected $file;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\DocumentBundle\Entity\Status")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="status", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
    * @var \App\DocumentBundle\Entity\Status
    *      @Groups({"elastica"})
    */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\DocumentBundle\Entity\UploadProfile", inversedBy="documents", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="document_document_uploadprofile",
     *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="document_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="uploadprofile_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     * @var \App\DocumentBundle\Entity\UploadProfile
     **/
    protected $uploadprofile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=7, scale=7, nullable = true)
     */
    protected $esScore;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->locked = false;
        $this->signed = false;
        $this->market = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->agency = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->channel = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->product = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /* Entity: Functions ************************************************************************/


    public function getCurrentDate(){
      return new \DateTime();
      }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function prePersist() {

        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

        if($this->created == null)
        {
            $this->created = new \DateTime("now");
        }
        $market = $this->getMarket();
        if(count($this->getAgency()) > 0){
          foreach($this->getAgency() as $agency) {
            if(!$this->market->contains($agency->getMarket())) {
              $this->addMarket($agency->getMarket());
            }
          }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function preUpdate() {

        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

        if($this->modified == null)
        {
            $this->modified = new \DateTime("now");
        }

        $market = $this->getMarket();
        if(count($this->getAgency()) > 0){
          foreach($this->getAgency() as $agency) {
            if(!$this->market->contains($agency->getMarket())) {
              $this->addMarket($agency->getMarket());
            }
          }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get statusStealth
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getStatusStealth()
    {
        return $this->status_stealth;
    }
    public function getStealthException(){
      if ($this->getEffective() < $this->getCurrentDate() && $this->getStatusStealth() == true){
        return true;
      } else{
      return false;
    }
  }

  public function show()
  {

    return array(
      "domain" => "document",
      "id" => $this->id,
      "info" => $this->getHeadline(),
      "title" => $this->name . ' - ' . $this->vkaNumber,
      "airlines" => $this->getAirline(),
      "agencies" => $this->getAgency(),
      "markets" => $this->getMarket(),
      "vkaNumber" => $this->vkaNumber,
      "path" => "documentBundle_view_document",
      "pathVariable" => "id",
      "pathValue" => $this->id,
      "bootstrapColor" => 'primary',
    );
  }


  /* Entity: Functions ************************************************************************/



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set headline
     *
     * @param string $headline
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setHeadline($headline)
    {
        $this->headline = $headline;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get headline
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHeadline()
    {
        return $this->headline;
    }

    /**
     * Set vkaNumber
     *
     * @param string $vkaNumber
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setVkaNumber($vkaNumber)
    {
        $this->vkaNumber = $vkaNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get vkaNumber
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVkaNumber()
    {
        return $this->vkaNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set linkedDocument
     *
     * @param string $linkedDocument
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setLinkedDocument($linkedDocument)
    {
        $this->linkedDocument = $linkedDocument;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get linkedDocument
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLinkedDocument()
    {
        return $this->linkedDocument;
    }

    /**
     * Set linkedDocumentExpires
     *
     * @param string $linkedDocumentExpires
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setLinkedDocumentExpires($linkedDocumentExpires)
    {
        $this->linkedDocumentExpires = $linkedDocumentExpires;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get linkedDocumentExpires
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLinkedDocumentExpires()
    {
        return $this->linkedDocumentExpires;
    }

    /**
     * Set active
     *
     * @param boolean $active
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setActive($active)
    {
        $this->active = $active;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get active
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getActive()
    {
        return $this->active;
    }

    /**
     * Set statusStealth
     *
     * @param boolean $statusStealth
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setStatusStealth($statusStealth)
    {
        $this->status_stealth = $statusStealth;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set locked
     *
     * @param boolean $locked
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setLocked($locked)
    {
        $this->locked = $locked;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get locked
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getLocked()
    {
        return $this->locked;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Set effective
     *
     * @param \DateTime $effective
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setEffective($effective)
    {
        $this->effective = $effective;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get effective
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getEffective()
    {
        return $this->effective;
    }

    /**
     * Set expires
     *
     * @param \DateTime $expires
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setExpires($expires)
    {
        $this->expires = $expires;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get expires
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getExpires()
    {
        return $this->expires;
    }

    /**
     * Set modified
     *
     * @param \DateTime $modified
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setModified($modified)
    {
        $this->modified = $modified;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get modified
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getModified()
    {
        return $this->modified;
    }

    /**
     * Set signature
     *
     * @param boolean $signature
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setSignature($signature)
    {
        $this->signature = $signature;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get signature
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getSignature()
    {
        return $this->signature;
    }

    /**
     * Set signed
     *
     * @param boolean $signed
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setSigned($signed)
    {
        $this->signed = $signed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get signed
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getSigned()
    {
        return $this->signed;
    }

    /**
     * Set internalCom
     *
     * @param boolean $internalCom
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setInternalCom($internalCom)
    {
        $this->internalCom = $internalCom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get internalCom
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getInternalCom()
    {
        return $this->internalCom;
    }

    /**
     * Set esScore
     *
     * @param string $esScore
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setEsScore($esScore)
    {
        $this->esScore = $esScore;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get esScore
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEsScore()
    {
        return $this->esScore;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param \App\DocumentBundle\Entity\DocumentType $type
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setType(\App\DocumentBundle\Entity\DocumentType $type = null)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return \App\DocumentBundle\Entity\DocumentType
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdBy
     *
     * @param \App\UserBundle\Entity\User $createdBy
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setCreatedBy(\App\UserBundle\Entity\User $createdBy = null)
    {
        $this->createdBy = $createdBy;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdBy
     *
     * @return \App\UserBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getCreatedBy()
    {
        return $this->createdBy;
    }

    /**
     * Set modifiedBy
     *
     * @param \App\UserBundle\Entity\User $modifiedBy
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setModifiedBy(\App\UserBundle\Entity\User $modifiedBy = null)
    {
        $this->modifiedBy = $modifiedBy;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get modifiedBy
     *
     * @return \App\UserBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getModifiedBy()
    {
        return $this->modifiedBy;
    }

    /**
     * Add agency
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Agency $agency
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function addAgency(\App\Entity\Agency $agency)
    {
        $this->agency[] = $agency;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove agency
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Agency $agency
     */
    public function removeAgency(\App\Entity\Agency $agency)
    {
        $this->agency->removeElement($agency);
    }

    /**
     * Get agency
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getAgency()
    {
        return $this->agency;
    }

    /**
     * Set signedBy
     *
     * @param \App\UserBundle\Entity\User $signedBy
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function setSignedBy(\App\UserBundle\Entity\User $signedBy = null)
    {
        $this->signedBy = $signedBy;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get signedBy
     *
     * @return \App\UserBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getSignedBy()
    {
        return $this->signedBy;
    }

    /**
     * Add comment
     *
     * @param \App\DocumentBundle\Entity\Comment $comment
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function addComment(\App\DocumentBundle\Entity\Comment $comment)
    {
        $this->comment[] = $comment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove comment
     *
     * @param \App\DocumentBundle\Entity\Comment $comment
     */
    public function removeComment(\App\DocumentBundle\Entity\Comment $comment)
    {
        $this->comment->removeElement($comment);
    }

    /**
     * Get comment
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getComment()
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }

    /**
     * Add market
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Market $market
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function addMarket(\App\Entity\Market $market)
    {
        $this->market[] = $market;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove market
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Market $market
     */
    public function removeMarket(\App\Entity\Market $market)
    {
        $this->market->removeElement($market);
    }

    /**
     * Get market
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getMarket()
    {
        return $this->market;
    }

    /**
     * Add airline
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Airline $airline
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function addAirline(\App\Entity\Airline $airline)
    {
        $this->airline[] = $airline;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove airline
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Airline $airline
     */
    public function removeAirline(\App\Entity\Airline $airline)
    {
        $this->airline->removeElement($airline);
    }

    /**
     * Get airline
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getAirline()
    {
        return $this->airline;
    }

    /**
     * Add product
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Product $product
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function addProduct(\App\Entity\Product $product)
    {
        $this->product[] = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove product
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Product $product
     */
    public function removeProduct(\App\Entity\Product $product)
    {
        $this->product->removeElement($product);
    }

    /**
     * Get product
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    /**
     * Add channel
     *
     * @param \App\ReferentialBundle\Entity\Channel1 $channel
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function addChannel(\App\ReferentialBundle\Entity\Channel1 $channel)
    {
        $this->channel[] = $channel;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove channel
     *
     * @param \App\ReferentialBundle\Entity\Channel1 $channel
     */
    public function removeChannel(\App\ReferentialBundle\Entity\Channel1 $channel)
    {
        $this->channel->removeElement($channel);
    }

    /**
     * Get channel
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getChannel()
    {
        return $this->channel;
    }

    /**
     * Get file
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }
}
```

**File.php (child class)**

```
<?php

namespace App\DocumentBundle;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Entity\File as BaseFile;

/**
 * This class extends the base file class. Only the mapped entity and table name are different.
 *
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Table(name="document_file")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class File extends BaseFile {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\DocumentBundle\Entity\Document", inversedBy="file")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * @var \App\DocumentBundle\Entity\Document
     */
    protected $entity;
}
```

I already tried to clean the cache, restart the server, update doctrine or commented the property out, but nothing has worked so far. Has anyone an idea how to ressolve this issue?

Comment: Why is Document in another namespace than File? If they are in the same folder you need to change that.

Comment: That was a legacy structure. I changed the namespace of File.php to App\DocumentBundle\Entity, but still get the same error message.